# Select items with no attributes outside a given set

Tags: mysql

I need help with a query in MySQL.
I have 2 tables, one named `cars` and one called `accessories` (this is fictional).

A car in the `cars` table carries a set of accessories in the table.
Car table looks like this.

```
ID
Name
Accessory 1
Accessory 2
Accessory 3
Accessory 4
Accessory 5
etc..
```

I then want the user to specify what accessories he wants with tickboxes.
Then run a query to show various cars from `cars` with *only* those accessories **or less**.

#### Example:

```
ID = 1
Name = Ford Mondeo
Accessory 1 = AC
Accessory 2 = Turbo

ID = 2
Name = Ford Mondeo SE
Accessory 1 = AC
Accessory 2 = Turbo
Accessory 3 = Cruise control
Accessory 4 = CD

ID = 3
Name = Ford Mustang
Accessory 1 = AC
Accessory 2 = Turbo
Accessory 3 = Cruise control
Accessory 4 = CD
Accessory 5 = DVD
```

If the user specified `AC`, `Turbo`, `Cruise control` and `CD`, then the 1st and 2nd car should show, but not the 3rd, since they did not tick `DVD`.

The result should not show any post with anything not "ticked".

I hope someone can help me with constructing a query for this operation.

Comment: Normalize your database.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Why not name the columns AC, Turbo, Cruise_Control, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as others have suggested, you should have one table for the cars, one for the accessories, and one *link table* listing which accessories each car has.  For a simple example, you could set up your tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE accessories (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (name)  /* for efficient lookups by name */
);

CREATE TABLE car_accessories (
  car INTEGER NOT NULL,
  accessory INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (car, accessory),
  UNIQUE KEY (accessory, car)
);
```

To list all cars that have no accessories other than `AC`, `Turbo`, `Cruise control` and `CD`, you can then use either a `NOT EXISTS` subselect ([SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/3QEbA47RyS)):

```
SELECT *
FROM cars AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT * FROM car_accessories AS ca, accessories AS a
    WHERE ca.car = c.id
      AND ca.accessory = a.id
      AND a.name NOT IN ('AC', 'Turbo', 'Cruise control', 'CD') )
```

or a `LEFT JOIN` ([SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/y4O8YmJ1oG)):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cars AS c
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( car_accessories AS ca
      JOIN accessories AS a
        ON ca.accessory = a.id
        AND a.name NOT IN ('AC', 'Turbo', 'Cruise control', 'CD')
    ) ON ca.car = c.id
WHERE ca.car IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema, it needs normalising

e.g.

```
Cars, ID, AccessoryID

Accessories, ID
```

Then

you example would be something like

```
Accessories
1, AC
2, Turbo
3, Cruise Control...
```

and Cars would be say

```
ID,Name
```

And CarAccessories

```
CarID, AccessoryID
```

After sorting that lot, an ALL query is what you want..